# SelectionKey with empty interest set

Tags: java, select, nio, socketchannel

I created an abstraction

`public interface Channel<R extends SelectableChannel & ReadableByteChannel, W extends SelectableChannel & WritableByteChannel>`

for `java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel`, it provides an `isBidirectional` method and getters to retrieve the write/read channel (which may or may not be equal). This channel and possibly multiple other instances of it are used with a dispatcher for i/o that encapsulates a selector.

Since I want to have non-blocking write, the dispatcher populates mutliple queues with ByteBuffers that should be written to the corresponding channels and adds `java.nio.channels.SelectionKey.OP_WRITE` to the key's interest set, if a write is due.

For bidirectional channels it's a simple update operation, since the read channel (== write channel),
is already processed with interest `OP_READ`. 
If the channel is unidirectional, I have to get the write channel (!= read channel) and register it with interest `OP_WRITE`.

---

**QUESTION**

What should I do after I have performed my write operation assuming the queue is empty now?
For bidirectional channels, I simply have to reset the interest set to `OP_READ`.

But how should I handle unidirectional channels, is it okay to invoke `key.interestOps(0);`, it does not violate the method's invariant

`(ops & ~channel().validOps()) != 0`.

The interest set of the (unidirectional) write channel would then be empty.

---

**IN SHORT**

Is `java.nio.channels.SelectionKey.interestOps(0)` a correct invocation, if I'm currently not interested in the selection key? Or should I remove the key?

Comment: I think your question is unclear.  It could really use an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For example, these queues are probably your own code, and I don't really know how they should be manipulated in your code.  Try to produce a code example that doesn't use the queues or anything but a single write channel and demonstrates the interest key you are concerned about.

Comment: I added an 'in short' section, I hope it is clearer now. It's not about the queues, it's about disabling a channel for a given selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it okay to invoke `key.interestOps(0);`

Yes, this is perfectly OK.

Comment: Can you give the reason why? and what happens when you invoke key.interestOps(0) ? It is not in the Java docs

Comment: @user1870400 Can you give one single solitary reason why it shouldn't be OK? There is nothing in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#interestOps-int-) that says so.

Answer (score 1):

it means that you are not interest for any operation of that key, hence this will reset the earlier operations which were of interest.

by doing so, you are telling selector  that for now ignore this key.